# Do twin spells have to be the same? (enlarge/reduce question)

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, metamagic, spellcasting

A sorcerer twin casts "enlarge/reduce"; enlarge on the group's fighter and reduce on the enemy soldier. Is this a valid way to twin a spell under RAW or do the casts have to be identical, either both enlarged or both reduced?